# All module bootstraps always run on one request

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, bootstrapping

I have two modules: admin, default.
Each has one bootstrap:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
     function _initSmth()
     {
          echo 'admin';
          die();
     }
}
```

and the default one:

```
 class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
    {
         function _initSmth()
         {
              echo 'default';
              die();
         }
    }
```

If I run site.ru or site.ru/admin/ it always returns 'admin'.
Why default bootstrap run with admin bootstrap?

Comment: Have you checked that site.ru isn't actually using the admin module? Check the request object and see what module/controller/action it is using to begin with.

Comment: Yes I did. It default index controller returns 'default' on $this->getRequest()->getModuleName(). And admin index controller returns 'admin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the way Zend works. If you enable module resource into your application config (tipically application.ini)

```
resource.modules=
```

All the modules are bootstrapped at bootstrap time. If you want to switch behaviors based on which module the request has been routed to you can plan using controllers plugin.

Consider that the first hook that is aware of which module/controller/action is the routeShutdown but depending what you need to do you can use other hooks.

Here is an example

```
Plugin_Test extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

public function routeShutdown (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

    switch($request->getModuleName()) {

        case 'default':
        // do something
        break;
        case 'admin':
        // do something else
    }

}
```